# Callback / asynchronous request in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I do a http request in nodejs with the following code

```
var buffer = "";
var postToPHP = function(data, path){

    var httpreq = require('http');
    var querystring = require("querystring");
    var data = querystring.stringify(data);

    var options = {
        host : 'localhost',
        path : path,
        method : 'POST',
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length' : data.length
        }
    };

    var buffer = "";

    var reqPost = httpreq.request(options, function(res) {

        res.on('data', function(d) {
            buffer = buffer+d;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
           console.log("buffer",buffer); //this logs the buffer correctly
           return buffer;
        });

    });

    reqPost.write(data);
    reqPost.end();

}

var buffer = postToPHP(message,path); //this buffer displays nothing because the call is async
```

I'd like to know exactly what is the standard procedure to "wait" for the server response in the nodejs or how to implement a callback that would react accordingly to what I want after I receive the message... Could someone give me an example of a callback on this please?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass in a callback if you're performing an asynchronous task inside a function:

```
var http = require('http'),
    querystring = require('querystring');

function postToPHP(data, path, cb) {
  var data = querystring.stringify(data);

  var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    path: path,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data.length)
    }
  };

  http.request(options, function(res) {
    var buffer = '',
        calledBack = false;
    res.on('data', function(d) {
      buffer += d;
    }).on('error', function(err) {
      if (!calledBack) {
        calledBack = true;
        cb(err);
      }
    }).on('end', function() {
      if (!calledBack) {
        calledBack = true;
        cb(null, buffer);
      }
    });
  }).on('error', function(err) {
    if (!calledBack) {
      calledBack = true;
      cb(err);
    }
  }).end(data)
}
```

Then use it:

```
postToPHP({ foo: 'bar' }, '/foo', function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.dir(data);
});
```

Comment: Yes, there is. However if you're less paranoid, feel free to omit the extra code and just call the callback without the conditional.